# How to remove K characters from a string such that there is a minimum of each character

Tags: string, algorithm, minimum

I want to remove *K* characters from a string such that the occurrence of each character is at a minimum.

For example:

String: `abcdefghijkllllll`

K: `5`

Answer: 12 (abcdeghijkl)

String: `ababac`

K: `4`

Answer: 3 (aac)

String: `aaaab`

K: `4`

Answer: 1(b)

I want to remove 5 characters. Those characters would be 5 `l`'s

What I've done so far is count the occurence of each character using a map

But I'm stuck as to what to do next.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string s;
int l, k;
map<char, int> m;
int main() {
    getline(cin, s);
    scanf("%d %d", &l, &k);
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        m[s[i]]++;
    }
    for(auto &x : m) {
        cout << x.second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is the minimum length of a string after removing the characters of any given string (can be sorted or unsorted).

You can remove any character in the String

#### Update:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string s;
int l, k;
map<char, int> m;
int main() {
    getline(cin, s);
    cin >> l >> k;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        m[s[i]]++;
    }
    for(auto it = m.end(); it != m.begin(); it--) {
        // cout << it->second << "\n";
    }

    vector<pair<int, int>> pairs;
    for (auto itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++) {
        pairs.push_back(*itr);
    }
    sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [=](pair<int, int>& a, pair<int, int>& b) { return a.second < b.second; } );

    for(auto it = m.end(); it != m.begin(); it--) {
        if(it->second - k >= 1) {
            it->second-=k;
            k -= it->second;
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto it = m.end(); it != m.begin(); it--) {
        sum += it->second;
        // cout << it->second << "\n";
    }
    cout << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The current problem with this is that it doesn't read all the characters and map them correctly to the map.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about what is the task and expected result? Fields are always sorted? You  can remove them only if they are next to each other and same...?

Comment: @libik updated.

Comment: Still not clear, so from `abac` I can do `abc`?

Comment: Yes, the inteded result would be abc given the K >= 1

Comment: can you provide the original source of this question?

Comment: @peter sorry, it was a white board challenge

Comment: could you please update your original question with a few **clear** examples of the input and desired result?

Comment: @peter yes, ive included two more

Comment: count each occurrence of letter , store them in a map. Sort the keys in order of their values and update keys as you remove K values.

Comment: @SomeDude I've sorted the map based on the values, but can you explain what you mean by update keys as you remove K values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain from your description and test cases what you're looking for. Your answer is returning the number of characters remaining in the string, and your updated function returns the `sum` variable. If that's the case why not just return the length of the string minus k?

Your second test case is:

```
String: ababac
K: 4
Answer: 3 (aac)
```

Removing 4 characters from "ababac" (length 6) would give it a length of 2, not 3. How does this work?

Can the characters be removed in any order? For the third test case you have:

```
String: aaaab
K: 4
Answer: 1(b)
```

Given the description: `I want to remove K characters from a string such that the occurrence of each character is at a minimum.` Removing 3 characters gives the result "ab". Removing the 4th could result in either "a" or "b". What do you do in this case?

There's a lot of ambiguity in this question, and the test cases are a bit confusing. For example, given "aabbccdddd" k=3, what would be the accepted answer? "abcdddd" or "aabbccd"? "abcdddd" would increase the number of characters that are at a minimum whereas "aabbccd" would reduce the number of the most frequently occurring character.

I've put together an answer using a max priority queue / max-heap (in Java) with the later example from above. This assumes that all your input is good.

```java
    import java.util.*;
    public class SO {

        //Helper class to put in the priority queue.
        class CharInt {
            char c;
            int count;
            public CharInt(char c) {
                this.c = c;
                this.count = 1;
            }

            void increment() {
                this.count++;
            }

            void decrement() {
                this.count--;
            }
        }

        public int minChar(String s, int k) {   
            Map<Character, CharInt> map = new HashMap<Character, CharInt>();

            for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
                if (map.get(c) == null) {
                    map.put(c, new CharInt(c));
                }else {
                    map.get(c).increment();
                }
            }

            //Makes a Max-Heap  from a PriorityQueue object. The comparator makes sure the top of the PriorityQueue is the character with the highest count.
            PriorityQueue<CharInt> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<CharInt>(new Comparator<CharInt>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(CharInt o1, CharInt o2) {
                    return - Integer.compare(o1.count, o2.count);
                }
            });

            //Add all values to the heap.
            for (CharInt c : map.values()) {
                maxHeap.add(c);
            }

            //Take the top value off, decrement its count, add it back to the heap. Do this k times.
            while (k-- > 0) {
                CharInt c = maxHeap.poll();
                c.decrement();
                maxHeap.add(c);
            }

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();     // Used to make output string. Can be left out.
            int sum = 0;

            //Remove every element from the heap and get its count value.
            while(!maxHeap.isEmpty()) {
                CharInt c = maxHeap.poll();
                for (int i = 0; i < c.count; i++) {
                    sum += c.count;
                    builder.append(c.c);                     // Used to make output string. Can be left out.
                }
            }
            char[] chars = builder.toString().toCharArray(); // Used to make output string. Can be left out.
            Arrays.sort(chars);                              // Used to make output string. Can be left out.
            System.out.println(chars);                       // Used to make output string. Can be left out.
            return sum;
        }
        public static void main(String...bannaa) {
            int s = new SO().minChar("abcdefghijkllllll", 5);
            int s2 = new SO().minChar("ababac", 4);
            int s3 = new SO().minChar("aaaab", 4);
            int s4 = new SO().minChar("abbbccc", 4);

            System.out.println(s + " " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s4);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijkl
ac
a
abc
12 2 1 3
```